# How can write data in GPIO with O_RDWR

Tags: linux, gpio

I have a GPIO pin. Process A use `open` of `sysfs` to read data from GPIO as follows:

```
fd = open("/sys/class/gpioN/value", O_RDWR)
read(fd, &value, 1);
close(fd);
```

With O_RDWR, **Can I write data to `gpioN` by other process**?

For example,

```
write(fd, "1", 1);
```

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this seem to appear regularly; they seem so odd to me, that I have to wonder if I really understand what's being asked. In general, yes, you can read and write the GPIO pin if you open the pseudo-file as you do. You can do it from the same process, or a different process. But, electrically, it makes no sense. If you program a pin as a input, then writing it won't change the voltage, so you can't use it as an output. And if you program it as an output, then trying to change the voltage externally -- use it as an input -- you'll probably damage the hardware. What am I missing?

Comment: @KevinBoone Thank you for your answer. I know that reading and writing into the same GPIO is should not, but my program must do it. If I set GPIO as output, do I need close and reopen GPIO before reading or writing data?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you do. If you set a GPIO pin as an output, any data you read will be meaningless, because you can't input on a pin set for output. The best that can happen is that you will read back the previous output. The worst is that you'll get random numbers. I'm sorry if I'm missing the point completely.